# rosservice call in bash causing issues

Tags: ros, rosservice, bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to use bash to execute a bunch of rosservice calls, one after the other. Some work but the ones that ask for position ones don't:

rosservice call /wam/cart_move "position:

- 0
- 0
- 0.5"

They work if I put them in terminal no problem, but I cannot bash call them.. Any suggestions as to why this my be the case?

Update: 21 Jan - @Wolf saved the day - had to include sleep command to allow the service to run.. Thank you ros answers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/118956/rosservice-call-in-bash-causing-issues/) by [kleinsplash](https://answers.ros.org/users/5014/kleinsplash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-01-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-01-17**:
How does your script file look like? What is the error messsage? I can call rosservice from a bash shell script without problems. Did you select bash (# !/bin/bash ) at top of your script?

**Comment by [kleinsplash](https://answers.ros.org/users/5014/kleinsplash/) on 2014-01-17**:
It's a typical .sh script:

#! /bin/bash

rosservice call /bhand/open_spread
rosservice call /wam/cart_move "position:

- 0
- 0
- 0.5"
  rosservice call /wam/cart_move  "position:
- 0.87
- -0.15
- -0.45"

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-01-20**:
What type of service is that?

**Comment by [kleinsplash](https://answers.ros.org/users/5014/kleinsplash/) on 2014-01-20**:
wam/cart_move - type wam_srvs/CartPosMove; float32[3] position
---; (http://code.google.com/p/gwam-ros-pkg/wiki/GWAMPackagewam_node); (http://code.google.com/p/gwam-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/wam/wam_common/wam_srvs/srv/CartPosMove.srv?spec=svn203&r=86)

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-01-20**:
What kind of error do you get?

**Comment by [kleinsplash](https://answers.ros.org/users/5014/kleinsplash/) on 2014-01-20**:
I dont get an error - this runs without a problem - but does not execute all the command (specifically the service call to /wam/cart_move)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try to add a sleep for a short time between your service calls (Or call with --wait ...)? Maybe your node is just busy if you call the services immediately one after another...

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kleinsplash](https://answers.ros.org/users/5014/kleinsplash/) on 2014-01-20**:
Thats it :) thank you.. I tried converting your comment to answer - but wasnt able to.. perhaps admin did the rest..

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-01-20**:
If this answer solves the problem, please click the checkmark item next to the question to mark it answered.